# Notice: Undefined index: getQuantityAndStockStatus

Tags: magento2, bundle-product, magento-enterprise-2

On Bundle product detail page I am getting below error.

I tried:

```
- sudo rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*  pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/log/* generated/*
- magento setup:di:compile
- magento setup:upgrade
- magento indexer:reindex
```

However, issue is still not resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, but I see you have a custom extension installed called `IVG_Notifyme`.
Try disabling that and see if the error reproduces.
If the problem goes away, contact the extension developer (if it's not you).
If it is you, then post in the question the code from `IVG\Notifyme\Pricing\ConfigurablePrice.php`